# I have started one new application from my app but getting msg like Activity not found

Tags: android

I want to start a another application from my application but I am getting message like "Activity not found" exception when I executes below code

```
 final Intent i = new Intent();
i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN); //might not be necessary
i.setClassName("com.cardmagic.in", "com.cardmagic.in.CardMAinActivity");
startActivity(i);
```

so please anyone can give me the solution of this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: go to mainifest and register your activity first.. then run it..

Comment: stackoverflow.com/questions/3872063/android-launch-an-application-from-another-application

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.package.address","com.package.address.MainActivity"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Check with this....

Answer (score 0):

Check registered activities in your manifest.

Check the com.cardmagic.in.CardMAinActivity in Intent filter

After that it will definitely gonna run

Answer (score 0):

In other application set intent-filter to activity that you want to start.

```
    <activity
        android:name=".YourActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="my.mime.type/my.mime.type"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

For launching use the following code

```
Intent it = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
it.setType("my.mime.type/my.mime.type");
startActivity(it);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following code...if    you are getting `ActivityNotFoundException` means either package name is incorrect or application with this package name doesnt exits

```
 Intent mIntent = mContext.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.cardmagic.in.CardMAinActivity");
                if (mIntent != null) {
                  try {
                      mContext.startActivity(mIntent);
                  } catch (ActivityNotFoundException err) {
                        // do something
                    }
                } else {
                    // do something
                }
```

package name should be define as

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.cardmagic.in.CardMAinActivity"
```

Comment: i'll run my project by inserting ur code but it shows intent null and also i remove mcontextlike this    Intent mIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.cardmagic.in");
    if (mIntent != null) {
      try {
         startActivity(mIntent);
      } catch (ActivityNotFoundException err)
      {
System.out.println("this exception"+err);        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("intent null");
    }

Comment: see wether you have  <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter> tag for com.cardmagic.in.CardMAinActivity?

Comment: hey, what is the value of mcontext object of context class will contain in above code.

Comment: mContext is nothing ..its just a context of an activity. if you are in activity there is no need of mContext or optional you can put this instead of mContext

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with your cases - should CardMAinActivity really be CardMainActivity?